# C# how to display or pass a value, on what you clicked on

Tags: c#, click

I have some code that creates panels with picture boxes in them. I would like something to tell me what picture box was clicked on. 
I'm using the following:

```
PicBx[z].Click += new EventHandler(clicked);
```

Do I need to assign a value on the click? Or is there a way just to display what you clicked on?

Comment: Does your `EventHandler` have an `object sender` parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The handler method gets the control that was clicked as its `sender` parameter.
You can cast it to `PictureBox` and do whatever you want with it.

Alternatively, you can add an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) as the handler:

```
PicBx[z].Click += delegate { SomeMethod(z, somethingElse); };
```

However, make sure [not to close over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: I'm using a foreach loop, so if I use the delegate it will make z whatever the last value that was inputted. Is there a way to make it unique to each Picturebox that was created?

Comment: Yes; you need to declare a separate variable inside the loop.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Got it! Put `int z2=z;` within the loop and used `PicBx[z].Click += delegate { clicked(z2, null); };` Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The clicked method does have an argument passed into it (Object sender). This is the PictureBox that was clicked.

Comment: But the problem is that there are multiple pictureboxes that are created via a foreach loop. Obkect sender will only have the last picturebox value created. I need to be able to click on whichever picture box was created and return a unique value for that picturebox.

Comment: @user: `sender` is not from a closure; it will always contain the actual PictureBox that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler will have two arguments in its signature: `object sender` and `EventArgs e`. The `sender` is the object that you clicked on, so you can cast it to `PictureBox` or whatever type it actually is, and you should be good to go.